# Simplest way to retrieve all messages of a Telegram channel in Java?

Tags: java, telegram

I hope this question is not too general.

I'm looking for a way to retrieve all the messages (including media) that have been posted on a Telegram channel, and also all the comments to each message (including commonly available metadata about the author, time of post, etc...) in Java.

I'm having a very hard time to find a solution: search results are polluted with the Telegram Bot API, which is, as far as I understand it, not what I need. I've seen there is a [TDlib library](https://github.com/tdlib/td) with JNI bindings, which seems a pain in the ass to install. I've also found this Maven repository for [org.telegram.telegramapi](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.telegram/telegramapi), but I have not been able to find a simple code snippet that explains how to initialize the library and perform the most common operations.

What is the best solution here? Is it one of the two I listed or I am missing something?

Comment: Have you read https://core.telegram.org/api#telegram-api ?

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't help much. I don't understand how to access those methods within Java.

Answer (score 0):

Check this, there is some language's example: https://github.com/tdlib/td/tree/master/example